# 1 motor and 180 degree servo or just 2 motors?

Tags: mobile-robot, raspberry-pi, servomotor

I am planning to use this motor: http://www.adrirobot.it/robot_kit/feetech_FT-DC-002/TGP01D-A130_TT-Motor.pdf Model: TGP01DA130 12215-48.
But I have some questions: How much a robot will be slower if it has 1 motor and one 180 degree servo instead of just 2 motors? And which one is the best option?

Comment: Determining the top speed of a robot is pretty hard to do even when you have all the information (mass of robot, battery voltage, battery chemistry, gear train, wheel size, motor driver, floor type, etc).  You don't provide nearly enough information for someone to tell you if 1 or 2 motors is better. Why not just try it out?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the second motor/servo for steering, I suggest you used a servo. To me, It's easier to operate for steering and more accurate.

Comment: good point, servos have "constant rotation" instead of just "on and off" like motors.  you'd be better able to calculate theoretical speeds with servos because you can give the command "rotate x degrees" and know the circumference of your wheel.